# Initializing RestKit's RKPaginator with fresh core-data

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have an `RKPaginator` that loads data from the server and saves it to Core Data. It all works like a charm when loading and paging. However, the items in Core Data are persistent so any time I reenter the viewcontroller or restart the App, all the previous paged data is still in Core Data.

I would like to start with a clean sheet when I start the app. How can I tell Core Data to flush its contents? I tried the following code but it seems to only work sometimes, and irregularly, probably timing errors from incoming data. I would actually really like to flush only when I get a successful reply from my Api-Request.

```
NSString *entityDescription = @"Activity";
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityDescription inManagedObjectContext:weakSelf.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *error;
NSArray *items = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in items) {
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
}
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Did you save after that code? Do your entities have a date (like the download date)?

Comment: No I didn't save. I will do that thanks. I also don't have a download date in the entity. That is not something the server is offering me. Would I need to set that after I get the data from the server?

Comment: If you want to purge after getting a response you need some way to tell what's new and what's old is all...

Comment: I can note the time when entering the ViewContoller and anything older gets deleted while anything loaded gets a new current time stamp.

Comment: You could, but you would have to reprocess all of the mapped items and then re-save the DB. Not a problem per-say but hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is to delete the Core Data store file from disk when the app starts and create a new one. This obviously won't work for keeping the data till after the request returns good data though.

For that, you need to be able to tell what is old and what is new. RestKit can do that for you, but if you're loading paged data it won't work well (it would tend to delete the page you had when you get a new one).

You could use code similar to what you have (which should work), but in the `success` block of the request. In the `success` block you have all of the new items, so you would just check if it was the first request (`BOOL` instance variable) and, if it was, delete everything that wasn't in the `mappingResult`.

Comment: The last solution is the one I want. The old data should be visible until new data arrives. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in a very similar situation, using RestKit and Core Data. The remote data is always the up to date source, so I want Core Data to "purge" what's not present in the remote DB.

I spent a while trying to do what you want to do - completely purging the local persistent store - and every way I tried seemed to cause issues.

RestKit has built in functionality to update CoreData for you and to remove those entities in CoreData that no longer exist in the remote data source (or that are no longer being returned by the API for particular calls).

It is called "Fetch Request Blocks".

```
- (void)setupFetchRequestBlocksForObjectManager:(RKObjectManager*)manager
{
    [manager addFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSURL *URL) {
        RKPathMatcher *pathMatcher = [RKPathMatcher pathMatcherWithPattern:@"article"];

        NSDictionary *argsDict = nil;
        BOOL match = [pathMatcher matchesPath:[URL relativePath] tokenizeQueryStrings:NO parsedArguments:&argsDict];
        if (match) {
            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Article"];
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[ [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"articleId" ascending:YES] ];
            return fetchRequest;
        }
        return nil;
    }];
}
```

In this example, I'm describing the API call that this Fetch Request Block is for, and then describing the CoreData request that should match it. Any Core Data objects that are not the same as those returned by the API call will be changed/deleted.

This example is for a very simple API call, but you can also include params in the matcher so that it only matches for more complex requests - [there's a good example of that on the RestKit site.](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html)

There's also another question on SO about it [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110445/restkit-how-to-remove-core-data-entries-to-keep-the-content-in-sync-with-the-se)

Comment: Were you using this example with RKPaginator? Would loading a second page note result in the first page's data getting deleted?

Comment: I'm not using RKPaginator, but I have tried it with paged API calls. You have to be careful that the NSFetchRequest returns the same page as the URL (including params) that you're calling - that it is a proper 'match'.
The example in the link does more with matching the params of the request. It is certainly more complex to do it that way, but it is what these Fetch Request Blocks are for, and hopefully better support for RKPaginator will come (if its not there already - please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: I managed to get the example from Wain to work quite good, so for the moment I will stick with that. But when I get more time I will try Fetch Request Blocks as I would like to learn as much RestKit techniques as possible. I will post again when I get that far. Thanks for the info.