# auto delete object from database using restkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

i'm using restkit to get list of objects from web service , i wanna make synch between server and my local database , so i added attribute is_deleted to the server once the object is deleted from the server the flag is_deleted = true , can i make restkit auto delete this objects ?? i searched the internet but i didn't find a direct way to do this ?

i just select the objects using predicate and remove them like

NSManagedObjectContext *context = object.managedObjectContext;

[context deleteObject:object];

Comment: possible duplicate of [RestKit: how to remove core data entries to keep the content in sync with the server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110445/restkit-how-to-remove-core-data-entries-to-keep-the-content-in-sync-with-the-se)